# Storage size of 'var' isn't known

Tags: c++

I have a program which works fine under VC++, but is giving me an error under GCC.

within **log.h**:

```
namespace logType {
    enum Enum {
        None = 0,
        Info,
        Warning,
        Error,
    };
    std::string Name[];
}
```

within **log.cpp**:

```
std::string logType::Name[] = {
    "None",
    "Info",
    "WARNING",
    "ERROR"
};
```

This works fine when I compile log.cpp. However, if any other file includes log.h, that file errors out:

`error: storage size of ‘logType::Name’ isn't known`

I've tried specifying the array size for Name[] in one or both of the files, but that just changes the error to that of redeclaration.

How do I get this to cooperate under GCC?

Comment: when do you get the error, when linking the *.o files or when generating the .o file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `extern` to `log.h`'s declaration of your Name. Your symbol appears in two places.

Comment: Yes. Functions do not need it (although it does not hurt) but variables declared in a header require extern.